# rules for overwriting vs clobbering when inheriting in Maven

Tags: maven

When inheriting from a parent POM, is there a list of which element types will be merged (i.e. the actual value in the child is the union of the parent values and the child values) vs which will be clobbered (i.e. if the child specifies a value, it overrides the parent value)?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of values inherited from parent pom [here](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) .

About that clobbering AFAIK for the leaf nodes if the item has no id then child's definition will override the parent value as in the dependency declaration and parameter values.

If there is an id you should use that id to override the value.

For the outer nodes like "dependency","plugins","repositories" the default behaviour is merge.

If for example there is different plugin definitions in both parent and child those will be merge. If there is a definition for the same plugin then the value in the child will override the parent's one.

Comment: In your second paragraph do you mean if the item "has an id"? How could it override a specific value from the parent if it has no ID?

Comment: as i said if you define a version in your dependency declaration in child, it will override the version defined in parent. Or if you define a parameter with the same name in parent, your new definition will override the value from parent. In both these cases there is no id.